# Prove A, B and C and independent.

Tags: probability, independence

I'm finishing my guideline of exercises from a course I'm doing of Probability and Statistics and I'm presented with the next problem:

Suppose A,B and C are events and you know that:

i. A is independent of B∩C and B∪C

ii. B is independent of A∩C

iii. C is independent of A∩B

iv. P(A) P(B) P(C) > 0 (P meaning probability)

then the objective is to prove that A, B y C are independent.

I tried rewritting P(A∩B∩C) with the expectations to get it to be equal to P(A)*P(B)*P(C) but i couldn't finde the way.

Comment: Do not [repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3647608/321264) your questions; edit them to add context.

Comment: I tried to do that in the past and my question was never reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ is independent of $B\cup C,$
$$P(A)[P(B)+P(C)-P(B\cap C)]=P(A)P(B\cup C)=P(A\cap (B\cup C))=P((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C))=P(A\cap B)+P(B\cap C)-P(A\cap B \cap C).
$$ 
Using the independence of $A$ from $B\cap C$ and adding to both sides,
$$
P(A)[P(B)+P(C)]=P(A\cap B)+P(A \cap C).
$$
Using the independence of $A\cap B$ from $C$ and of $A\cap C$ from $B,$
$$
P(A)[P(B)+P(C)]=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)=\frac{P(A\cap B \cap C)}{P(C)}+\frac{P(A\cap B \cap C)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A\cap B \cap C)[P(B)+P(C)]}{P(B)P(C)}.
$$
Cancelling terms and multiplying,
$$P(A)P(B)P(C)=P(A\cap B \cap C).$$

Comment: I kept getting to the point where I have P(A∩B) + P(A∩C)= P(A)*(P(B) + P(C)) and getting stuck. Thank you!